# Replace THIS when moving from MainWindow to function

Tags: c++, qt

I have moved the following code from the MainWindow constructor to a function within the MainWindow.

```
void allFilters(QStringList list){
    QWidget *w = new QWidget(this);
    w->setFixedSize(300,200);
    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;

    foreach(QString filt, list){
        QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox(filt, this);
        checkbox->setChecked(true);
        vbox->addWidget(checkbox);

        connect(checkbox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(cbstate(int)));

    }

    w->setLayout(vbox);
    w->show();
}
```

`this` is now causing me problems. I assume there is an alternative but I'm unaware of what it is?

Hopefully someone can help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like allFilters isn't a member function within MainWindow.  `this` is only valid within non-static member functions as it points to the instance of the object.

You'll need to define it like

```
void MainWindow::allFilters(QStringList list)
```

Comment: That's such a stupid error to make! I included MainWindow:: in all my other functions and didn't here. Sorry, and thanks for pointing it out.